# Limit list length in redis

Tags: database, redis

I'm using redis lists and pushing to new items to a list.  The problem is I really only need the most recent 10 items in a list.

I'm using `lpush` to add items to a list and `lrange` to get the most recent 10.

Is there anyway to drop items after a certain number? I'll end up with lists that may have 1,000's of items and can cause performance issues with latency.

Thank you!

Comment: How are you interfacing with Redis? CLI? Python? C#?

Comment: It should be something like `LTRIM list -10 -1` just like I answered detailed below.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

After every `lpush`, call `ltrim` to trim the list to 10 elements

See http://redis.io/commands/ltrim

Comment: Wouldn't retrieving the current list length and only inserting if the length is below 10 be a better performing solution for large entities?

Comment: @bornSwift, wouldn't your solution keep the 10 earliest entries instead of the 10 most recent?

Comment: @TerryLewis, yes good point.  Didn't see the "most recent" in the question.. oops

Answer (score 38):

You can use [LTRIM](http://redis.io/commands/ltrim) **intermittently** after any LPUSH, **no need to call LTRIM after every LPUSH as that would add to overall latency in your app** ( though redis is really fast, but you can save lots of LPUSH operations )

Here is a pseudo code to achieve an LTRIM on approximately every 5th LPUSH:

```
LPUSH mylist 1
random_int = some random number between 1-5
if random_int == 1:  # trim my list with 1/5 chance
   LTRIM mylist 0 10
```

Though your list may grow to be a few elements more than 10 elements at times, but it will surely get truncated at regular intervals.
This approach is good for most practical purposes and saves a lot of LTRIM operations, keeping your pushes fast.

Comment: You can almost smell when a piece of advice comes straight from someone's experiences in production ;)

Comment: How can you be sure that getting a random number and checking if it is something isn't more expensive than an `LTRIM` call?

Comment: @fiatjaf Mostly because of LTRIM being an over the network operation, however if both operations are part of a single Lua script, we might have to benchmark. However, I do strongly feel, that the random number operation is going to be simpler than LTRIM in both cases.

Comment: @DhruvPathak If one is using a language/library that supports pipelining, then it is not necessary to write a script to save the round trip time.

Answer (score 12):

The following code,

- pushes the item to the list,
- keep the size fixed to 10,
- and returns the most recent 10 elements

in a **transaction**.

```
MULTI
LPUSH list "item1"
LTRIM list 0 9
LRANGE list 0 9
EXEC
```

Comment: @PaulT.Rawkeen why? it can be achieved with Reids builtin commands (wrapped in transaction), I don't see a reason to make it a lua script.

Answer (score 12):

No one has ever mentioned the real solution about **storing only most 10 recent items**.

Let's create a sample list with 15 items (here just numbers):

```
RPUSH list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Now indicate offset from the end of the list:

```
LTRIM list -10 -1
```

Show list

```
LRANGE list 0 -1

 1) "6"
 2) "7"
 3) "8"
 4) "9"
 5) "10"
 6) "11"
 7) "12"
 8) "13"
 9) "14"
10) "15"
```

Now you can add new items and run trim:

```
RPUSH list 16
LTRIM list -10 -1

 1) "7"
 2) "8"
 3) "9"
 4) "10"
 5) "11"
 6) "12"
 7) "13"
 8) "14"
 9) "15"
10) "16"
```

Answer (score 9):

Just an alternative. According to [official doc](https://redis.io/commands/lpush) of `LPUSH`, it returns the length of the list after the push operations. You can set a threshold length like `k` (in your case k > 10) and call `LTRIM` when returned length is bigger than `k`. Sample pseudo code as follows:

```
len = LPUSH mylist xxx 
if len > k:   
  LTRIM mylist 0 9
LRANGE mylist 0 9
```

It's more controllable than random method. Greater `k` triggers less `LTRIM` but with more memory cost. You can adjust `k` according to how often you want to call `LTRIM` since calling extra command is more expensive.

Comment: This is a very smart implementing, great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Calling `LTRIM <list-name> -1 -10` after `LPUSH <list-name> <item>`
is the simplest answer. Many had covered it.

You must do this two operations in a transaction or must use Lua script to ensure the operation is atomic.

Comment: Why a Lua script specifically?

Comment: Lua ensures the operation is atomic. On code level, if you are using Lua for some other work, using Lua instead of transaction is simpler